# how to import ouibounce to Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, npm-scripts

how to import ouibounce npm package to Angular 6?

[ouibounce GitHub repo](https://github.com/carlsednaoui/ouibounce)

[ouibounce npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ouibounce)

Please help me to find out how to import ouibounce npm package to angular. I can install it via npm, but don't know how to import it.

Comment: Angular 2+ or AngularJS? you have both tags included

Comment: sorry @vidalsasoon Angular 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a full working example on [GitHub](https://github.com/PdUi/stack-overflow-answer-repos/tree/master/ng-ouibounce).

The highlights for your question are as follows.

In the project directory run: `npm install --save ouibounce`

Then to utilize it in a component, you will need to give it a reference to a dom element. The way I'm doing that is through Angular's `ViewChild` decorator.

In the `app.component.ts` file I have:

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as ouibounce from 'ouibounce';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  title = 'ng-ouibounce';
  @ViewChild('modal') modal: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    ouibounce(this.modal.nativeElement, { aggressive: true });
  }
}
```

In the `app.component.html` I have `<div #modal class="modal">hello world!</div>`

The `#modal` attribute gets matched when Angular creates the AppComponent and assigns its value to the `modal` property. This is only available at a certain point in the lifecycle of the component, which is why I'm accessing it in the `ngAfterViewInit` method.

I don't fully understand the `ouibounce` library, but outside of setting up the mouse listening events to evaluate when the mouse is going off the page, it seemingly only changes the display of the element it is given to `display: block;`. I have a number of styles in the `styles.css` file that are just there so that it is readily apparent that the library is working when you pull down the example.